# log4j2: TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not triggering file roll-over

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j 2.0-rc1, StructuredDataMessage and EventLogger to perform dynamic logging.

Below log4j2.xml configuration meant to:

- rotate log files on hourly basis OR after file reaches 64 MB (whatever comes first)
- archive logs that does not satisfy the file pattern

  ```
  <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
          <Route>
              <RollingFile name="RollingFile-${sd:type}"
                           fileName="${log.path}/${date:yyyyMMdd}/${date:yyyyMMddHH}-${sd:type}-${hostName}.log"
                           filePattern="${log.path}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/%d{yyyyMMddHH}-${sd:type}-${hostName}.%i.log.gz">
                  <PatternLayout>  
                      <!-- %K{v} stands for the message passed in StructuredDataMessage map with key "v" -->
                      <!-- %n stands for new line -->
                      <Pattern>%K{v}%n</Pattern>
                  </PatternLayout>
                  <Policies>
                      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
                      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="64 MB"/>
                  </Policies>
                  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="999"/>
              </RollingFile>
          </Route>
      </Routes>
  </Routing>
  ```

  ```
  <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
  </Root>
  ```

There are two issues:

1. logging is performed on an "old" log file few minutes after new hour triggers:

   Feb 19 20:13 2014021919-planoperator-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log
   Feb 19 20:13 2014021919-planprogress-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log
   Feb 19 20:13 2014021919-planstats-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log
   Feb 19 20:08 2014021919-sim-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log
2. whenever JVM is restarted, log4j abandons "old" files un-archived

   Feb 19 20:13 2014021919-planstats-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log
   Feb 19 20:29 2014021920-planstats-mdmlocal.mobidia.com.log

Answer (score 1):

The first issue you mention may be a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-520 - but feel free to add another ticket if this doesn't cover what you're seeing.  (In that case, please mention steps to reproduce, what actually happens and what you expect to happen. The more detail, the better.)

About the second issue (log4j abandons old files un-archived), can you create a ticket for this in the Log4J2 issue tracker?

Comment: Remko. I have created two Jira issues: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-550 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-551